# How can I interchange odd pages and even pages position in the header using lyx?

Tags: formatting, header-footer, lyx

I intend to write my PhD thesis in Lyx, but I am not getting to interchange between odd pages (to the left of the header) and even pages (to the right of the header). At the LaTeX preamble in lyx configurations, I set:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot{}

\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}

\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
```

However, lyx only considers `[RO]` command, and it does not accept LE.

Any suggestions to make it work?

Comment: you need twoside in the document class options (I have no idea how to do that in lyx).

Comment: Document->Settings->Page Layout->Two-sided document